# Conditonal updating a multiindex frame using pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have 2 frames:
frame1
Loc--- Time -- Code -- Value
FRA ----2008 ---- F- ---- 1.224
CAN ----2007 ---- G ------1.99
MEX ----2010 -----I -------3.55
frame2(multi index one)
Country ------Ccy -------2007 ------2008 ------2009
FRANCE------  EURO-------5.225 ------6.299------7.555
CANADA------  CANADIAN---53.65--------4.445-----8.445
MEXICO ------ Peso------15434.154--------14564.3 -----4.455
I would like  to convert all columns 2007/2008/... to Euro.
It means that if the Ccy is aleady EURO, it should remain, if not retrieve the exchange rate from frame1 and update the value.
I'm stuck here, tried different ways but nothing satisfactory.

Comment: Can you please format your input into something that can be easily copied into a DataFrame? Please see [How to make a good reproducible pandas example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Is there any other table correlating Loc and Ccy from both dataframes?

Comment: Loc is the 3 first characters of Country. 
country and Ccy are part of the frame2 index, while 2007, 2008, 2009 are columns

Comment: the exchange rate is from currency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering the multindex, and using the method merge to facilitate the operation, the following code:

```
frame2['Country'] = frame2.index.get_level_values(0)
frame2['Loc'] = frame2.index.get_level_values(0).str[0:3]
frame2['Ccy'] = frame2.index.get_level_values(1)
merged = frame1.merge(frame2)
merged.loc[merged.Ccy != 'EURO', ['2007', '2008', '2009']] = merged.loc[merged.Ccy != 'EURO', ['2007', '2008', '2009']].values * merged.loc[merged.Ccy != 'EURO', ['Value']].values
merged.loc[merged.Ccy != 'EURO', 'Ccy'] = 'EURO'
frame2 = merged[['Country','Ccy','2007','2008','2009']]
frame2.set_index(['Country', 'Ccy'], inplace = True)
```

Produces the desired output:

[image]

**EDIT:** now updating also the Ccy column with the new currency.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  But I get this error on the first line 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'Country'

Comment: @Crovish, I considered the column names as you defined in the question (below). Are they different from this?
Frame1: Loc,Time,Code,Value
Frame2: Country,Ccy,2007,2008,2009

Comment: Frame1 is inline with  what you described, but frame 2 has columns 2007,2008,2009. Country and ccy are the index

Comment: Edited to consider the indexes. Take a look, @Crovish.

Comment: No it doesn't really. As you still have local Ccy. example after conversion, Canada Ccy should be Euro

Comment: Hi @Crovish, I edited the answer to update also the Ccy column. Please, check now.